# Ask for the condition of guess number game

Tags: c++

I am a newbie, i have some question:
I am coding a guessing number game, player enter the random number range, guess number, guess limit. When player enter the guess number out of the random range entered, the program require player to  enter the guess number again. However, I tested my code, I entered the number range [ 3,8 ] and the guess number is 1, this number is out of range, the program didn't force me to enter the guess number again but I had to enter the guess limit. Please hint me what's wrong with my code and help me to fix this code. Thanks!

```
#include iostream

#include cstdlib

using namespace std;

int randnum(int min, int max)
{
    return min + (int)(rand() * (max - min + 1.0) / (1.0 + RAND_MAX));
}

int main()
{
    int max;
    int min;
    int guessnum;
    int guesscou = 0;
    int guesslim;
    bool outofguess = false;

    cout << " Enter max min of random value range = \n ";
    cin >> max >> min;
    cout << " Enter your guess number = \n ";
    cin >> guessnum;
    cout << " Enter your guess limitation = \n";
    cin >> guesslim;

    // enter guess loop
    while (guessnum != randnum(min, max) && !outofguess) {

        // guessnum condition
        while (guessnum <= max && guessnum >= min) {
            cout << " Unvalid number, please enter again ";
            cin >> guessnum;
        }

        // guess limitation
        if (guesscou <= guesslim) {
            cout << " Please try again \n";
            cin >> guessnum;
            guesscou++;
        }
        else {
            outofguess = true;
        }
    }

    if (outofguess) {
        cout << " you win";
    }
    else {
        cout << " you lose ";
    }
}
```

Comment: You should create *one* random number. In your current code you create a new random number each time the loop iterates, making it impossible to correctly guess the number since it will always change.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude it is indeed a more challenging version of the traditional setup.

Answer (score 1):

You want the user to guess again if the number is lower than the minimum or higher than the maximum. But the logic in your while loop says exactly the opposite. It should read

```
while (guessnum < min || guessnum > max) {
    cout << " Unvalid number, please enter again ";
    cin >> guessnum;
}
```